# Extjs: Is there any way to change the default values of the properties I specified of the components?

Tags: extjs, default

I want to change the "labelAlign" of all field component in the page to "right".

Now, I have to add the default config below to all panel in the page to implement that.

```
    defaults:
    {
        labelAlign: 'right',
        labelSeparator: "："
    }
```

Is there any once code way to change the default values of the properties I specified of all the extjs components in the page?

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Setting defaults in the highest level container of the view should apply that config to any children that do not already have a value set.
If one or more of the children (field components) already have a labelAlign config then you might try doing:

```
allYourFields = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield');
Ext.forEach(allYourFields, function(field){
    field.labelAlign = 'right';
});
```

Comment: I have tested that althought set the defaults the highest level container of the view, the default values can't apply to its child's child.

`Ext.onReady(function (){ new Ext.container.Viewport(  {   defaults:{labelAlign:"right"},   items:    [     {      xtype:"textfield",      fieldLabel:"field1"     },     {      xtype:"panel",      items:       [        {         xtype:"textfield",         fieldLabel:"field2"        }       ]     }    ]  })});`